# How to access Json (which was a result of HttpMessage) in C#?

Tags: c#, json, .net, string, json.net

I am writing two applications (Web API's) in .NET . From the app A I want to call a method in Controller of app B using Http Request.
Here

```
 using (var askPensionerDetails = new HttpClient())
            {
                double pensionToDisburse = 0;
                askPensionerDetails.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:55345/api/pensionerdetails/");
                var responseTask = askPensionerDetails.GetAsync("getById?pan=" + inputOfPensioner.PAN);
                responseTask.Wait();
                var result =responseTask.Result ;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                     var readTask = result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<object>();
                     readTask.Wait();
                     return Ok(readTask.Result);
                }
            }
```

The output for this in postman is

```
{
    "name": "bunk seenu",
    "dateOfBirth": "1990-01-02T00:00:00",
    "pan": "ABCD12351E",
    "salaryEarned": 45000,
    "allowances": 500,
    "pensionType": 1,
    "bankDetails": {
        "bankName": "SBI",
        "accountNumber": "SBI00001BS",
        "bankType": 0
    }
}
```

That was a desired output. But the problem is how to access the properties like bankdetails,name,pan,salaryEarned.

I have tried using readTask.Result["name"] but it is throwing error.

I have also tried using **result.Content.ReadAsStringASync();**
But the output in postman is

```
{
    "name": [],
    "dateOfBirth": [],
    "pan": [],
    "salaryEarned": [],
    "allowances": [],
    "pensionType": [],
    "bankDetails": [
        [
            []
        ],
        [
            []
        ],
        [
            []
        ]
    ]
}
```

I don't have class associated with the result type of Json for statement readTask = result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync(); (As per design constraints).

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#how-to-read-json-as-net-objects-deserialize):

> If you have JSON that you want to deserialize, and you don't have the class to deserialize it into, you have options other than manually creating the class that you need:
>
> - Deserialize into a [JSON DOM (document object model)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter) and extract what you need from the DOM.
>
>   The DOM lets you navigate to a subsection of a JSON payload and deserialize a single value, a custom type, or an array. For information about the [JsonNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode) DOM in .NET 6, see [Deserialize subsections of a JSON payload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-6-0#deserialize-subsections-of-a-json-payload). For information about the [JsonDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument) DOM, see [How to search a JsonDocument and JsonElement for sub-elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#how-to-search-a-jsondocument-and-jsonelement-for-sub-elements).
> - Use the [Utf8JsonReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter#use-utf8jsonreader) directly.
> - Use Visual Studio 2019 to automatically generate the class you need:
>
>   - Copy the JSON that you need to deserialize.
>   - Create a class file and delete the template code.
>   - Choose **Edit** > **Paste Special** > **Paste JSON as Classes**. The result is a class that you can use for your deserialization target.

Comment: Hey, that worked absolutely fine. Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Newtonsoft.Json

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(readTask.Result);
var name = jo["name"];
if(string.IsNnullOrEmpty(name)){
///some code 
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. but that did not work. The result was { ValueKind :[] }

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ki2WgU#   here is sample.